# Linq to SQL: order an asp gridview objectdatasource by an arbitrary column name

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview, linq-to-sql

For the following code, I'm using LINQ to SQL to page data for a GridView bound to an ObjectDataSource and sorting by the "ID" column.

```
public IQueryable<MYDATATYPE> GetMYDATATYPE(int maximumRows, int startPageIndex, int startRowIndex, string orderByColumnName)
{
    // page query
    var query = Context.MYDATATYPEs.Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows);

    // ordering by the ID column
    query = query.OrderBy(x => x.ID);

    return query;
}
```

Instead of sorting by the ID column, is it possible to sort by the column name specified in the orderByColumnName parameter instead?

I thought I could just put "orderByColumnName" in the OrderByFunction, like this,

```
query = query.OrderBy(orderByColumnName);
```

But it gives me this error:

> Error  CS0411  The type arguments for method 'Queryable.OrderBy(IQueryable, Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Here's the ASP object data source using the function:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
     SelectMethod="GetMYDATATYPE" SelectCountMethod="GetMYDATATYPECount" 
     TypeName="Paging.MyData" EnablePaging="true" 
     SortParameterName="OrderByColumName">
   <SelectParameters>
     <asp:Parameter Name="maximumRows" Type="Int32" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="startPageIndex" Type="Int32" />
     <asp:Parameter Name="startRowIndex" Type="Int32" />
   </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Linq To SQL you can't do what you want to do. I always add a switch statement to extend my query depending on what the string variable contains. It's ugly but I didn't find any other solution yet...

```
switch (orderByColumnName){
    case "column1":
         query = query.OrderBy(p => p.column1);
         break;
    case "column2":
         query = query.OrderBy(p => p.column2);
         break;
    default:
         query = query.OrderBy(p => p.column1);
         break;
}
```